# iPhone 4 updated to iOS5, phone is not listed as a device in XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios5

I've just finished **updating my iPhone 4  from iOS 4.2 to iOS 5.** Once I re-opened my xcode project, I no longer see the phone as one of the devices to run on. What steps do I need to take to add the phone back to XCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the organizer and, in the devices section, accept the iPhone for development.

Comment: Thank you, now I need to know how to update Xcode to iOS5, otherwise I still cannot develop on the device!

Comment: Download Xcode 4.2 from [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios), read the about "About Xcode.pdf" for instructions on deleting your current version and install Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to update the complete Xcode. Instead just download the iOS5 SDK and paste it in your "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/" directory. Restart the xcode once and you should be able to run your app on the device.